# How to limit the process-number of mapserver-cgi started from Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, process

The Apache-webserver starts in out configuration a CGI-script for some requests. That is a shell-script, that basically starts a mapserver with some parameters. As the mapserver-process uses many resources, we want to limit the number of processes started at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

apart of doing some logic into your scripts you 
use some mechanism that is built into apache see
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-apache-setting-perl-cgi-script-limits.html